Android Studio: Split screen - how to remove upper and lower bands
This is my issue (tested on Android 13):

My app works in fullscreen mode always, but when I show another app in split screen mode I can't get rid of the top and bottom two bands.
All the apps open in split screen don't have them. Only mine.
This is my code:
Theme style:
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorBackgroundDashboard</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font_agencyfb_bold</item> -->
</style>

Main Activity:
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    Log.d(TAG, "onWindowFocusChanged...");

    if (hasFocus)
        enableImmersiveMode();
}

...
private void enableImmersiveMode()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "enableImmersiveMode...SDK: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) 
    {
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat controller = new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(getWindow(), getWindow().getDecorView());
        controller.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
        controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
    }
    else 
    {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
        );
    }
}

